# Excel index ,if and And

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets in excel. Sheet1 has A, B, C and D columns. Sheet2: A, B, E as columns. I want compare Sheet1 and Sheet2 columns (A&B) and write C from Sheet1 only if A&B in both sheets matches.

Eg:

Sheet1

```
A B C D
```

Sheet2

```
A B E
```

Add column C in Sheet2 only if A&B columns in both sheets matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vlookup` function.
In Sheet1 you need to make a new column consisting of a and b at the beginning, for example:
Sheet1:

```
A  B  C 
1  2  a
2  3  b
4  6  c
```

Sheet1 after changes:

```
new_column_A  old_A  B  C
          12   1     2  a
          23   2     3  b
          46   4     6  c
```

New_column_A can be created using formula `=old_A1&B1`
If you have this in your Sheet1 you can use `vlookup` function in your Sheet2 in column C to look for the values from Sheet1.

Sheet2

```
A  B  C
2  3  b
1  3  #N/D!
4  6  c
5  8  #N/D!
```

Your formula for C column would look like that:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1&B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4,4,0)
```

If you don't want the `#N/D!` values you need to add `IF` condition:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&B1,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$4,4,0))=TRUE,"",VLOOKUP(A1&B1,Sheet!$A$1:$D$4,4,0))
```

Result:

```
A  B  C
2  3  b
1  3  
4  6  c
5  8
```